# Adding formula in field calculator when new attribute is text type?

Tags: field-calculator

I added a new text attribute to my table. I would like it to print the values "y" or 'n", for when an attribute in the table is other a specific cut off it will code Y, and then that attribute is equal to or below that specific cut off number it will code "n".

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to indicate whether you are using the field calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop or QGIS, please?  If it is ArcGIS then are you wanting to use the Python or VBscript parser?  If it is ArcGIS and Python then I suspect this answer will help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22413

Answer (score 1):

The following approach should get you going:

[image]

[image]