# How to use field calculator in this situation

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator

How to use this formula in field calcultor in ArcMap.
for example:
      A = Field1
      B = Field2

```
  if A =<B
      C = B
  else:
      C = A
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using conditional statements in ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21916/using-conditional-statements-in-arcgis-field-calculator)

Comment: Assuming neither value is `None` this is the same as the trivial Python expression `max(!A!,!B!)`. The [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/using-the-calculate-field-tool.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_0428AC1238E64D1CA9810EAD06396AED) for Field Calculator has multiple examples, and the UI tool will help you build the function. Please make an attempt, then [Edit] the question to reflect any problem you may encounter.

Answer (score 2):

@Vince is right and this could be solved using the `max(!A!, !B!)` expression. However, if you had a more complex situation you could use a custom function. In Arcmap you can write a function on the code block space and then call it where you usually write the expression.

Your function (code block) could look something like:

```py
my_function(field1_value, field2_value):
    if field1_value <= field2_value:
        return field2_value
    else:
        return field1_value
```

Then you can call it using the following expression:

```
my_function(!A!, !B!)
```

Of course, you need to specify Python as the parser.